# salesforce1 Visualforce page iOS 9 issue

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, ios

I have a visualforce page that has the basic structure , and the elements are populated dynamically via jquery . It also uses bootstrap . The problem is the page loads as expected in iOS 8 but not iOS 9 . Any pointers to this would be good .

Thanks and Regards,
BK

Comment: any indication this is related to visualforce aspects ? May be more specific to browsers, html or javascript ?

Comment: Hi samuel, I have checked in browser it doesn't show any error , and as i said , it works in salesforce1 app iOS8

Comment: What in particular is causing the problem ?
Googling I found that there are issues with jQUery in iOS9. I think you should find a way to debug javascript on iOS9 to figure out what is causing the problem https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an workaround , i have wrapped the div with static height to give a auto scroll bar which works , and i am not using jQuery Mobile. Even with this workaround the iOS 9 scroll bar is bad , but far better than what it was.

- you can add webkit-scroll : touch  to fix this.